# Mega-cmd ls not working with remote link

Tags: shell, synology

I installed mega-cmd tool https://www.synology.com/en-uk/dsm/packages/MEGAcmd and am using it in shell, but I am not able to list the remote directory.
I installed mega-cmd on synology NAS and use it from CLI via ssh.

I have the version `MEGAcmd version: 1.4.0.0: code 1040000` installed.
See:

```
$ mega-cmd
mega-cmd

.======================================================================================================================================================================================.
|                                                                    __  __ _____ ____    _                      _                                                                     |
|                                                                   |  \/  | ___|/ ___|  / \   ___ _ __ ___   __| |                                                                    |
|                                                                   | |\/| | \  / |  _  / _ \ / __| '_ ` _ \ / _` |                                                                    |
|                                                                   | |  | | /__\ |_| |/ ___ \ (__| | | | | | (_| |                                                                    |
|                                                                   |_|  |_|____|\____/_/   \_\___|_| |_| |_|\__,_|                                                                    |
|                                                                                                                                                                                      |
|                                                            Welcome to MEGAcmd! A Command Line Interactive and Scriptable                                                             |
|                                                                   Application to interact with your MEGA account.                                                                    |
|                                                               Please write to support@mega.nz if you find any issue or                                                               |
|                                                                 have any suggestion concerning its functionalities.                                                                  |
|                                                       Enter "help --non-interactive" to learn how to use MEGAcmd with scripts.                                                       |
|                                                            Enter "help" for basic info and a list of available commands.                                                             |
`======================================================================================================================================================================================´
[Initiating server in background. Log: /var/services/homes/<user>/.megaCmd/megacmdserver.log]
<user>:/$ ls https://mega.nz/folder/Jw9ClZ7L#a8vWwpJTWC3l1km3PGmzIg                                                                                                     
[API:err: 21:56:28] Couldn't find https://mega.nz/folder/Jw9ClZ7L#a8vWwpJTWC3l1km3PGmzIg                                                                                               
<user>:/$ version                                                                                                                                                       
MEGAcmd version: 1.4.0.0: code 1040000                                                                                                                                                 
<user>:/$
```

why is that?

The link https://mega.nz/folder/Jw9ClZ7L#a8vWwpJTWC3l1km3PGmzIg leads to public directory which can be listed without any credentials without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I need to login using

```bash
logout
login https://mega.nz/folder/Jw9ClZ7L#a8vWwpJTWC3l1km3PGmzIg
```

and then the `ls` works.